# Facebook API Unity - How can we upload image to Facebook without encode to png

Tags: facebook, image, unity-game-engine

This code i found on Facebook developers. It works fine with small screen, but it crashes with screen 2000x2000. 
I found that occurs because of encode to png takes a lot of memory.
I use another way by capturing screen first, loading image by using www, and upload on Facebook.
The problem is www needs to use binary image to upload.

- Can i upload to Facebook without encode to png (because i load from
  local file)?
- Does Facebook API has another way to upload image?

  ```
  yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

  var width = Screen.width;
  var height = Screen.height;
  var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
  // Read screen contents into the texture
  tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
  tex.Apply();
  byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

  var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
  wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");

  FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, Callback, wwwForm);
  ```