# Facebook Unity Upload Image w/ Facebook Dialog

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-uploading, facebook-unity-sdk

We currently allow users to post images to their FB wall by using FB.Feed() with a URL of existing images on our CDN and we can include a description, a link, caption, etc.. The interface for posting the image is great because it's built by Facebook and gives the ability to choose who sees it (friends, me only, etc.).

We now want to allow users the ability to post images of their creations in the game, which obviously can't be pre-taken images on our CDN, and we'd prefer avoiding the route of uploading all the images to our CDN then using FB.Feed().

I know it's possibly to upload an image using [FB.API()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633224/facebook-api-unity-how-can-we-upload-image-to-facebook-without-encode-to-png) but this requires us building a custom popup to allow the users to type what they want to say for the message of the image rather than using the built-in popup from FB.Feed() and it doesn't give the options of who sees the post and as far as I can tell, it doesn't let us add a link, description and caption.

**TLDR: Is FB.API() the only way to UPLOAD an image to a user's wall? If so, this requires  building a custom interface for it instead of using the built-in FB.Post() interface, right?**

Thanks,
Colter

Edit: I didn't see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215946/upload-picture-to-facebook-from-unity) until now, but it's a similar question but I want to know if there is the ability to add a description, link and caption to the image AND use the built-in FB interface.

Comment: There currently isn't a way to upload screenshots without FB.API().  It does sound like an interesting idea to have something like that for FB.Feed() though.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste from Brian Jew's comment above:

"There currently isn't a way to upload screenshots without FB.API(). It does sound like an interesting idea to have something like that for FB.Feed() though."